# The Select Deployment Target does not show any device but USB device and other emulators are active

Tags: android-studio

I have updated version (3.2) of android studio. I have my USB device recognized perfectly and installed a virtual device but nothing show up in the select deployment target window. I think it may be a bug. If any one know how how to fix it kindly guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not seeing any devices, it is probably an adb error. Run `adb kill-server; adb devices` from the command line to restart the adb server.

If your devices show up, it might be that your devices have versions of Android that are below the minSdkVersion you have set for your app. In build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml you specify the minimum OS version that is supported by the app. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms and https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning for more information.